# How do I verify that an input is one from a pre-approved list? (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a code where the user has to input their name, and only allows access to the rest of the program if the name is on a pre-approved list, how do I do this? I'm very new to coding so the only thing that I have done so far is ask for the input with this:

`name = input ("welcome! please input your name > ")`

but I don't know how I can use this to only allow certain people in.
thank you for your help.

Comment: `if name in [<list of names here>]:` Would be a good start. See the [tutorial for flow-control](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) in the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

you can use exit() command.
Refer the code below:

```
approved_name = ['ram','shyam','mohan']   #list of approved names
name = input ("welcome! please input your name > ")
if name not in approved_name:   #checking if name is present in the list or not
    exit()                    #exit if name not in list
print(name)  # if name is present, print the name
```